# phpexcel doesn't work in preprocess function for drupal 7

Tags: drupal, phpexcel

I'm trying to use phpexcel to parse .xls files but I always get the same error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found
```

I have installed the phpexcel module without any errors. Where is problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to enabling the module, you need to download the [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library (version 1.7).

After that PHPExcel library can be extracted in any libraries folder you want (sites/*/libraries). You should have `sites/*/libraries/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks! New in Drupal, forget to load library :(
Problem solved by use `<?php libraries_load('PHPExcel'); ?>`